# UIViewController does not receive dealloc or viewDidUnload when dismissed

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uikit, automatic-ref-counting

**UPDATE:  I made a mistake in my debugging - this question is not relavent - please see comment below.**

**Note:  I am using Automated Reference Counting**

When my app starts - I present a view controller inside a `UINavigationController` with `presentViewController:animated:completion`.  That view controller loads a second view controller on to the navigation stack.  The second view controller uses `[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` to dismiss itself.  My issue, is that neither dealloc nor viewDidUnload are ever called in the first view controller.  However, with instruments, I can see that the view controller is no longer allocated once the presented view controllers are dismissed.  The code that presents the first view controller is

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated                                                                                                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];                                                                                                                                                                                                          

    //  check if our context has any accounts                                                                                                                                                                                                
    if( [self.accounts count] == 0 )                                                                                                                                                                                    
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        //  Display the Add Account View Controller                                                                                                                                                                                          
        MySettingsViewController *settingsVC = [[MySettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MySettingsViewController" bundle:nil];                                                                                                 
        settingsVC.appContext = self.appContext;                                                                                                                                                                                             

        UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsVC];                                                                                                                              
        navVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;                                                                                                                                                                    

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)                                                                                                                                                      
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            //  Display the Add Account View Controller                                                                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            navVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;                                                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

       [self presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:nil];                                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
}
```

So, I do not have any references to settingsVC that should be sticking around but I do not know why my dealloc is not being called.  Any help would be great.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  I put the dealloc method that I was testing for in the wrong view controller. So my dealloc is being called which makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't get called because you haven't correctly released your view controller.

You allocate both `settingsVC` and `navVC` with `alloc` and thus get owning references to both that you must later release which you didn't do.

You can do it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated                                                                                                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];                                                                                                                                                                                                          

    //  check if our context has any accounts                                                                                                                                                                                                
    if( [self.accounts count] == 0 )                                                                                                                                                                                    
    {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        //  Display the Add Account View Controller                                                                                                                                                                                          
        MySettingsViewController *settingsVC = [[MySettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MySettingsViewController" bundle:nil];                                                                                                 
        settingsVC.appContext = self.appContext;                                                                                                                                                                                             

        UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsVC];
        navVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;                                                                                                                                                                    

        // At this points, "settingsVC" is additionally retained by the navigation controller,
        // so we can release it now.
        [settingsVC release];

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)                                                                                                                                                      
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            //  Display the Add Account View Controller                                                                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        else                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            navVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;                                                                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

        [self presentViewController:navVC animated:YES completion:nil];

        // At this point "navVC" is retained by UIKit, so we can release it as well.
        [navVC release];
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
}
```

An alternative would have been to `autorelease` both right away.

Comment: I am using Automatic Reference Counting - is this still the case?  Sorry about that - I thought I included that in my question.  I have updated it to reflect that.

Comment: Of course ARC makes a difference here... well, in that case I don't know what's going on, sorry.

Comment: Can you tell me if my assumption that either dealloc or viewDidUnload should be called - meaning is my understanding of memory management and UIViewControllers correct?

Comment: Yes, both should be called once the corresponding view controller is dismissed.